# Would adding the customer domain to our organization as re-seller work, or would there be unintended consequences?

Tags: account-management, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I work for a small web development company that offers to set up and manage billing for G Suite accounts as a value-added service to our customers.  We typically create the account and enter the business credit card for billing.  But this is problematic for updating/cancelling billing methods, since we need the account holders credentials to do this.

Is there a good way that we can manage the billing and technical (domain) setup for the account, without having to log in as the user after the account is set up?

I am aware of the Google Cloud Partners program and the Reseller Console, but we currently don't sell enough accounts to qualify.  We are not looking to profit or mark up the G Suite accounts, it is simply done as a courtesy to customers who want to simplify the setup and billing process.

Would adding the customer domain to our organization work, or would there be unintended consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't suggest to have multiple domains within your primary account, keep in mind that sometimes users request some specific settings and these settings may not be able to work if the domain is not the primary domain of the G Suite account, I would suggest to contact the Google Partner Program team and explain your situation they may be able to help. https://support.google.com/work/reseller/answer/6182389?hl=en or contact G suite support.